# IFTTT activity paused suddenly

Tags: 9.0-pie, ifttt

I have a Nokia 6.1 with several geofencing based Applets to turn on/off the ringer, etc.  All of these recipes I got from IFTTT.  I just realized that none of them have run since December 6th.  Any idea what's going on?  My phone is a Nokia 6.1 running Android Pie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to be certain, but it seems like opening IFTTT on my Android smart phone fixed my problem.  Although that isn't very helpful in a way, since you have to notice that IFTTT isn't working and open it.  I don't see a way of preventing the problem.  Maybe I could set an IFTTT applet to send myself a daily "everything is okay" email and then if I didn't get the daily email I would know to check on it?  This might not do anything to help problems with the geofence based applets like I use though.